# Finding out about allowed/denied permissions

Tags: android, ios, firebase

I need to know how can we find out if the user has allowed or denied permissions we need for our app to be running.
Is this something I can log in analytics?

Thanks.

Comment: Probably. Which permissions specifically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a plug-in called [permission_handler](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler) which works for both Android and iOS.

Check for permissions on iOS:

```
var status = await Permission.camera.status;
if (status.isUndetermined) {
  // We didn't ask for permission yet.
}

// You can can also directly ask the permission about its status.
if (await Permission.location.isRestricted) {
  // The OS restricts access, for example because of parental controls.
}
```

> Call `request()` on a `Permission` to request it. If it has already been granted before, nothing happens.
> `request()` returns the new status of the `Permission`.

Or alternatively on Android:

```
bool isShown = await Permission.contacts.shouldShowRequestRationale;
```

Comment: We are using swift for iOS, can we still benefit from this flutter package?

Comment: @uiuxdesigner I think you can, you might need XCode though. Hav you followed the linked set-up steps?